# Repeatedly scrape data from same url with a time delay

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to consistently scrape a single webpage over a period of time to monitor some values and how they are changing within that period

I have no experience in web-scraping and I'm a little confused as to why my scrapy spider runs once and hangs.

I am attempting to run the spider through a 'main.py' script as follows:

```
timecheck = timeit.default_timer()

while (timecheck) < 30:
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        settings = get_project_settings()
        crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)
        crawler.crawl(mySpider())
        crawler.start(stop_after_crawl=False)
    time.sleep(5)

print("Finished crawl, time elapsed: %s" % str(timecheck))
```

My spider script is as follows:

```
class poeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spidername"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ["myurl.com/page1"]
        allowed_domains = ["myurl.com"]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)


    def parse(self,response):

        datavar = response.xpath("/mydata").extract()
        print(datavar[:3])
```

PS: A different issue, but related:

I'm also looking to store the data in a list or variable of some kind between scrapes so that I am able to compare the values while the program is running, ideally without any file I/O, which is my reasoning for using a 'main.py' though I'm also at a loss for how to pass the data in the `parse` function of the spider to anywhere where I can make such comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the logic in spider itself:

```
import scrapy
import logging
import time
from scrapy import signals, Request

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = ['first_url']

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_idle, signals.spider_idle)
        return spider

    def parse(self, response):
        # parse page
        pass

    def spider_idle(self, spider):
        time.sleep(30)
        # after 30 seconds crawl the same page again
        logging.info('starting a crawl again!')
        self.crawler.engine.schedule(Request(self.start_urls[0], dont_filter=True), spider)
        raise DontCloseSpider
```

In this example when spider goes idle after it will chill out for 30 seconds and then crawl start url again, and keep repeating this untill it's killed or stopped.

Comment: I am getting the error `crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_idle, signals.spider_idle)
NameError: name 'signals' is not defined` when trying to use this spider.

Comment: oh sorry I missed the import. It should be imported from scrapy, see my edit.

Comment: Ok this works very well thank you. Also `Request` should be imported or 
 use `scrapy.Request`. Can this also be edited to repeat a series of url's in a cycle?